# Connect Raspberry Pi 3B to Tablet WiFi hotspot, then SSH

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, hotspot

I wish to connect Raspberry Pi 3B to Tablet WiFi hotspot, then SSH from tablet to Raspberry Pi.

For travelling, I will have a data SIM in Galaxy Tab, so can set up a hotspot.

Connect Pi to the WiFi hotspot.

SSH from Galaxy Tab to the Raspberry Pi, so I can use the Tablet monitor and keyboard on the (headless) Raspberry Pi.

(I already do this, but when both Pi and Tablet are both connected to a network)

Comment: I'm confused. Do it. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the input techraf. Since the Pi is headless, i can SSH in from the android, but first have to have the Pi connected to a network - hopefully the Android's hotspot. @techraf

Answer (score 1):

*I would post this as comment, but I'm not allowed to due to lack of reputation*

For the initial setup you will need to access the raspberry pi by monitor and keyboard. then you need to configure your raspberry pi to autoconnect to the hotspot of your android device. then you need to find out the ip address of your raspberry pi. then you should be able to use your desired ssh-application to connect to your raspberry pi using that local ip address.

Actually it should even work without knowing the ip address using the domain `raspberrypi.local`.

Comment: Just for your info, this answer ended up in a review queue (usually low-quality stuff ends up there). If enough people deem your answers poor, those will be deleted and you may be restricted to 1 answer per day. (I see you're trying to help, just wanted to warn you).

Comment: that is the drawback, that users with low reputation are not allowed to comment, which i totally don't understand!

Comment: I agree it's inconvenient and frustrating, but don't worry: if you fit in the community, you'll get 50 points soon enough. If everyone is allowed to comment, mods will hang up in the closet when they see all that spam they'll have to clean up.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your helpful advice. Apologies for my (unavoidable) delay in replying. I tried to vote you up Julian, but think I am still to 'reputation-less' to help. I am still learning my way through the forum etiquette.

Comment: My Pi is set to auto start tightvncserver when I boot it up. The Pi auto connects to my home WiFi network, although I'm not sure why! So SSH-ing to the Pi from the tablet has been simple. But when away from the home network - @Julian your clue to 'configure your raspberry pi to autoconnect to the hotspot of your android device' was the prompt I needed thanks. I have yet to do this - I have found a few posts on this - but most seemed rather complicated, so I will need to spend more time looking into this.